# Actionscript 3 - Is it ok to have a bunch of code inside an event listener handler?

Tags: actionscript-3, apache-flex, actionscript, flash-cs5, flex4.5

I'm creating a GUI, but only if things go ok, so can i

addEventListener(Event.Complete, go) to something and in the go function create my GUI (grafical elements such as labels, lists, squares)?

Is it ok to do that?

Comment: it'll be hard to tell without some code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes that is perfectly fine. The go function isn't part of the event listener.

```
function go(e:Event):void {
// do something
}
```

The sample above requires the event parameter from the listener (e:Event).

But you can modify the function so that the parameter is optional so you can call the go function any time you want

```
function go(e:Event = null):void {
// do something
}
```

The example above will be triggered by the listener and also by typing

go();

Comment: @crooksy88, I agree with what you say on the possibility of using a function both as an event handler and as a function that can be called from elsewhere, by making the e parameter optional, but I don't understand what you mean by "the go function isn't part of the event listener"? Given that addEventListener(Event.Complete, go) can be read out as "add the listener go to the event Event.Complete", wouldn't it be more accurate to say that go _is_ the listener, rather than "the go function isn't part of the event listener"?

Comment: It's probably more accurate to say "add an listener for the event COMPLETE, and call go() which it happens". All you're storing is the function callback, not the function itself

Comment: I'd say in 'human readable terms' it's... Create a listener for the COMPLETE event and add it to whatever you're adding it to. When the COMPLETE event occurs, call the go function. As I see it the listener is a completely separate object to the go function, the only connection is the fact that one is calling the other.

Comment: Yes, I see know what you mean, and you are probably right, both divillysausages and crooksy88. The addEventListener() method is called on the object that is expected to dispatch the event, and the function (go in this example) is the event handler function, rather than the listener (although the AS3 documentation says "addEventListener(type:String, listener:Function..." and "listener:Function — The listener function that processes the event").

Answer (score 3):

Technically it's fine. crooksy88 gives a good example of supplying a default value for the event parameter to make the function more versatile.

However, for the sake of semantics, clarity, and maintenance I would usually prefer to separate things more. So mine might be set up more like this:

```
protected function onLoadComplete(e:Event):void {
    initAppSettings();
    createUI();
    startApp();
}
```

It makes it much easier to understand the flow of the app and what each part does just by reading the function names. When I come back to this later, I'll know that my UI is created in the function named `createUI` and not have to figure out that it gets created in an event handler with a cryptic name like `go` or `handleEvent`.

Also, if I want to change the flow of my app, say to pop up a dialog once the load is complete before the UI is created, I just have to move around some function calls, instead of moving around large chunks of code.